# Can i inject component without interface use windsor

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I like ioc. Earlier, i use Spring in Java, now, i want use DI in C#.
I found castle.windsor. But it does not seem to direct injection class.

Now, I try this, but fail.... Someone, can you help me fix it? Or, tell me, What DI framework can i use?

Program.cs

```
using System;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace InjectionConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.Install(new MainInstaller());

            var service1 = container.Resolve<Service1>();

            service1.Say();

            // clean up, application exits
            container.Dispose();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class MainInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly());
        }
    }
}
```

Service1.cs

```
using System;

namespace InjectionConsole
{
    class Service1
    {
        private Service2 Service2 { get; set; }

        public void Say()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, I m Service 1, let me call Service 2");

            Service2.Say();
        }
    }
}
```

Service2.cs

```
using System;

namespace InjectionConsole
{
    class Service2
    {
        public void Say()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, I m Service 2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The main point of "inversion of control" is to invert the dependencies so that the depending class depends on an interface of a service rather than on the actual implementation. If you are not using interfaces you are eliminating the core benefit of IOC containers and the mentioned pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is similar to another but with one hair-splitting difference:

```
public class Service1
{
    private readonly Service2 _service2;

    public Service1(Service2 service2) {
        _service2 = service2;
    }

    public void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, I m Service 1, let me call Service 2");

        _service2.Say();
    }
}
```

First, the class itself would be written exactly the same way whether or not you're using a container like Windsor. The class has to "get" its dependency (an instance of `Service2`) from somewhere. So we put it in the constructor. `Service1` expects whatever creates it to supply a `Service2`. Since you're using the container, the container creates `Service1`, it sees in the constructor that it needs a `Service2`, and it supplies that.

Making `_service2` a `readonly` field emphasizes that once it's created (the constructor is done executing) `Service1` has no further control over the value of `_service2`. It's set and cannot be changed, not even within `Service1`. That's important because we don't want `Service1` to *control* that dependency. We want it to *require* that dependency. It just takes whatever value is passed in and uses it.

Again, that's a hair-splitting difference. If you *don't* make `_service2` `readonly` you probably wouldn't change it anyway. But this makes clear that you *can't* change it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you. But fail reason is " An unhandled exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll "

Comment: Which component isn't registered?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you wanna resolve Service2 in your Service1 instance. You can achieve that by constructor injection

```
using System;

namespace InjectionConsole
{
    class Service1
    {
        public Service1(Service2 s2) {
            this.Service2 = s2;
        }

        private Service2 Service2 { get; set; }

        public void Say()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, I m Service 1, let me call Service 2");

            Service2.Say();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But fail reason is " An unhandled exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll ".

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't mark the `Service1` and `Service2` classes as `public`, which will make them internal by default. The `Classes.FromThisAssembly()` method loads public types only, unless you explicitly tell it to load nonpublic types as well (which is discouraged by the way!). Check [the docs](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md#registering-non-public-types) on the castle windsor GitHub docs page.